# Accessing localhost on IIS7 from another computer on the network

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, localhost

I recently upgraded computers to Windows 7 Professional and am running IIS7. When I'm on my computer I can easily access localhost through my web browser but when I try from another computer on my network (replacing localhost with my computer name) it doesn't work. I also tried using "computername.domain.com" and still no luck. I can access other computers running Windows XP and IIS 5 but I'm having no luck accessing my own from another computer. I checked and my IIS7 has anonymous users enabled. Am I missing any other setting? Is this an IIS7 thing or am I missing a setting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please provide more specifics, such as the error message received?

Comment: do you have a firewall enabled on the windows 7 machine?  from another machine can you "telnet 192.168.0.1 80" assuming 192.168.0.1 is the win7 machine?

Comment: Michael: It's actually not giving me any errors. The browser just says that it can't connect to <computer-name>

Johnh: I just tried to telnet and it couldn't connect. Do you know where I can setup my firewall in Win7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Johnh said it is most likely your firewall.

Open up port 80 on your firewall or whatever port you are hosting the local site on should it be a nonstandard port.

+1 for testing with telnet. Will give you a quick and definit answer on if the Web Server has the proper port open.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I configure the open ports in Windows 7?

Comment: I just opened port 80 and now it works perfectly. Thanks! (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall)

Answer (score 6):

**Campo is correct, you most likely need to open a port. Here's how: (on windows 7)**

1. Open Control Panel
2. Windows firewall
3. Select advanced settings
4. Select Inbound rules
5. Select "New Inbound Rule"

   Specify local ports 80, 8081. 
   Allow Domain

   (More details at: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall)

Answer (score 0):

go to Control Panel>Windows Firewall>Allowed Programs and make sure that **World Wide Web Services (HTTP)** is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel
Windows firewall
Select advanced settings
Select Inbound rules
Select "New Inbound Rule"

Specify local ports 80, 8081. Allow Domain

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete answer:

1. Before these steps, Check that IIS Service is Started. (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> World Wide Web Publishing Service -> Status:Started).

You most likely need to open a port. Here's how: (on Windows 7)

2. Open Control Panel
3. Windows firewall
4. Select advanced settings
5. Select Inbound rules
6. Select "New Inbound Rule"
7. Specify local ports 80, 8081. Allow Domain

   (More details at: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall)
8. Go to Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Allowed Programs and make sure that World Wide Web Services (HTTP) is checked.
9. Command Prompt (cmd) -> IPConfig -> Get your Current IP
10. Use this address IP:Port; to see site in another device.